# What is the problem with this python code indentation error?

Tags: python

I am new to python and was trying to do a web scraping project. I was referring to a code on [github](https://github.com/AgrimNautiyal/glassdoor-review-scraper) - main.py
When I run the code I get this error. I tried to check spaces and tabs but I could not fix it. Can someone help me!

> File "main.py", line 158 
>       <<<<<<< HEAD
>       ^IndentationError: expected an indented block

```
 def scrape_status(review):
        try:
            res = author.text.split('-')[0]
        except Exception:
            logger.warning('Failed to scrape employee_status')
            res = np.nan
        return res

    def scrape_rev_title(review):
        return review.find_element_by_class_name('summary').text.strip('"')

    def scrape_years(review):
<<<<<<< HEAD
        try:
            first_par = review.find_element_by_class_name(
                'reviewBodyCell').find_element_by_tag_name('p')
            if '(' in first_par.text:
                res = first_par.text[first_par.text.find('(') + 1:-1]
            else:
                res = np.nan
        except Exception:
=======
        first_par = review.find_element_by_class_name(
            'reviewBodyCell').find_element_by_tag_name('p')
        if '(' in first_par.text:
            res = first_par.text[first_par.text.find('(') + 1:-1]
        else:
>>>>>>> 7a5082d8ae61d93721d9ec8deb4ddda3d21cfb47
            res = np.nan
        return res

    def scrape_helpful(review):
        try:
<<<<<<< HEAD
            #helpful = review.find_element_by_class_name('count')
            helpful = review.find_element_by_class_name('voteHelpful').find_element_by_class_name('count').find_element_by_tag_name('span')
=======
            helpful = review.find_element_by_class_name('helpfulCount')
>>>>>>> 7a5082d8ae61d93721d9ec8deb4ddda3d21cfb47
            res = helpful[helpful.find('(') + 1: -1]
        except Exception:
            res = 0
        return res

    def expand_show_more(section):
        try:
            more_content = section.find_element_by_class_name('moreContent')
            more_link = more_content.find_element_by_class_name('moreLink')
            more_link.click()
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Comment: You seem to have checked out a file in the middle of a [merge conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git). You'll need to get that resolved somehow.

Comment: It appears you are trying to execute code that has merge conflicts

Comment: `<<<<<<<< HEAD` is not a Python statement; it's a marker from `git`'s file comparator.

Comment: You might want to check the project your link is forked from instead.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `<<<<<<< HEAD`, what do you think this means? Do you think it is a valid part of Python code? Why? What effect should it have?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove these lines

`<<<<<<< HEAD`

`=======`

`>>>>>>> 7a5082d8ae61d93721d9ec8deb4ddda3d21cfb47`

`<<<<<<< HEAD`

`=======`

`>>>>>>> 7a5082d8ae61d93721d9ec8deb4ddda3d21cfb47`

These are likely due to git merge conflicts and not actual valid Python code.

Removing these lines would still not solve your problem. You have to resolve merge conflicts.

Comment: @glibdud. Yeah You are correct. Updated my answer to reflect that.